# How do I use rectangular local tiles in android mapbox?

Tags: android, geolocation, mapbox, android-assets

Brand new to Mapbox.

I'm using the Android SDK version and have local (not cached, nothing from a server) tiles. I would like it if the tiles were not required to be square, but could be rectangular. I'm seeking an example and documentation on how to load local tiles from my assets folder. Right now my tiles are simply stored as .png files in "./assets/map/tiles/zoom/x/y.png" naming convention, but I could change it easily if that helps.

I don't see any examples or documentation anywhere. The code looks like it isn't designed to handle non-square tiles and it isn't clear on what I would do to get my tiles from a local source. I could make my tiles square if that's a problem, but I can't load from a server since the app will be used where there is no data connection.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Tiles are required to be square in the Android SDK. While it would be nice to support rectangular, elliptical, etc tile shapes, it would be unclear what geographical area they represented. And computers love squares, very literally - rectangles are performance bottlenecks in some cases. So, you'll need to use squares.